# Azure New-AzureManagedCache Error: Value cannot be null

Tags: caching, azure

I'm using Azure PowerShell for Create A Cache and I used `New-AzureManagedCache -Name test -Location "East Asia" -Sku Standard -Memory 1GB` to invoke. The shell has rendered the error `Value cannot be null`.

```
PS C:\> New-AzureManagedCache -Name test -Location "East Asia" -Sku Standard -Memory 1GB
New-AzureManagedCache : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: subscriptionId
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureManagedCache -Name test -Location "East Asia" -Sku Standard -Memory 1GB
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureManagedCache], ArgumentNullException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ManagedCache.NewAzureManagedCache
```

Then I tried using `New-AzureManagedCache` to find that the error happened in the variable of `-Location`.

```
PS C:\> New-AzureManagedCache

cmdlet New-AzureManagedCache at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name: test
Location: "East Asia"
New-AzureManagedCache : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: subscriptionId
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureManagedCache
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureManagedCache], ArgumentNullException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ManagedCache.NewAzureManagedCache
```

And what kind of value I can input.
Thanks!

Comment: I have resolved.It's my fault!I did not log my account,Sorry

Comment: Have the same issue, I ran set-azuresubscription and select-azuresubsctription, didn't help. What exactly did you do to resolve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Updated: Add-Account is what I had to do.