# Azure deployment fails with gitlab

Tags: git, azure, deployment, gitlab, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure web app running connected to a GitLab Repository. When I push new code to the GitLab Repo, the deployments fails and I get an error stating "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: url"

It seems like this has been asked on here before but unfortunately there were no answers. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that GitLab is not directly supported from Azure Portal. However, there are some manual steps that can be used to set it up. You can find them [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Continuous-deployment).

Also, make sure you are running a recent build of GitLab. Per [this issue](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1773), `7.7.2` is tool old, and `7.11.0` or later works.

Comment: More precise than my answer, plus I am not an "Architect on the Azure team". So +1.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The packaged GitLab VM in Azure from Bitnami is extremely old (7.1.1) and that was the issue. Ended up redeploying an actual GitLab VM instead of the pre-package and it works correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

As [commented here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667885/6309), check if this is an authentication issue (i.e. being logged with the right account to the Azure instance in order to initiate the deployment)

The authentication should involve [`Add-AzureAccount`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495128.aspx), through for instance a [powershell session](http://techitpro.com/connecting-powershell-to-azure-account/).